# iOS 5 - Getting image like add contact button

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to customize the accessory view of a UITableViewCell, so I need a UIImage. 
I want that image to be like the "Add Contact" type button (That blue plus).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. If I set user interaction disabled it just does not have a click interaction and behaves like an image.

```
UIButton *contactAddButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
[contactAddButton setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];
cell.accessoryView = contactAddButton;
```

Comment: Except that tapping an image in a cell will select the cell. Tapping a button with `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO` won't do anything and because it's a button *everywhere* else in the system, your users will be confused as to why it doesn't do anything.

Comment: But if I click the button (or any other place in the cell) it will select the cell and push another view. It behaves just like the one of the default accesory buttons (i.e. UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton) . I can't see why they will be confused.

Comment: Are you saying that the button is forwarding touch events to the cell? Interesting...

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that by creating a `UIButton` with the `UIButtonTypeContactAdd` type and adding it as the `accessoryView` of your cell.

```
UIButton contactAddButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
cell.accessoryView = contactAddButton;
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it overrides my didSelectRow event. I want to select the entire row, not pressing the button if I click inside the button. I want it to behave as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one here: http://blog.twg.ca/2010/11/retina-display-icon-set/

Comment: This is a good icon set but not what I am looking for. I need a blue image like the Add contact button.

Comment: You can get the icon image from this set and create a button like that. If you want exactly same effect, you can create a UIBarButtonItem (Although I would advise UIButton over it).